# Die Maus ist ein Tier, or Die Maus ist eine Tier?

Tags: gender

I'm trying to learn German on my own, and I'm not sure if in the phrase "Die Maus ist ein/e Tier", what gives gender to ein/e is the fact that the mouse is feminine, or Tier is a neutral noun. Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Minor correction: *das Tier* is a neutral, not a masculine noun. Though that doesn't change the idea of your question.

Comment: The question is somehow surprising (although it' not surprising that the grammars dissagree), since in Spanish/Italian (or whatever your language is) the rule is the same as in German. And I cannot think of a macabre language where this rule does not hold, but if somebody knows let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The article always depends on the case and gender of the word it refers to. The first article refers to Maus (feminine, Nominativ) and the second one refers to Tier (neutral, Nominativ). So

> **Die Maus** ist *ein Tier*.
>
> **The mouse** is *an animal*.

Answer (score 3):

These have no relation in German. There is no such requirement in German, that these should have the same gender. Thus, "Die Maus ist ein Tier" is correct.

Comment: What do you mean with "they have no relation" - who is "they"?

Comment: @Arsak Maus and Tier. Maybe "these" would be better English?